# Busca char em Arraylist de objeto

Tags: java

Estou aprendendo java na faculdade e estou com dificuldades de desenvolver a lógica para fazer busca em um Arraylist. Quero saber se existe senha cadastrada pelo atributo tipo, as senhas foram geradas com um valor char(tipo) e um valor int(numero) e concatenados dentro do ArrayList. Ex senhas: R-1,P-1,C-1.

Quero pesquisar através do metodo Caixa1 primeiramente na lista, apenas as senhas iniciadas com P respeitando a fila, da primeira cadastrada até a última, e depois de todas encontradas e eliminadas, então pesquisar por C e R sem necessidade de prioridade, essas duas últimas serão aleatórias de acordo com a posição na fila.

Deixa exemplificar de outra forma:
Digamos que eu adiciono senhas nessa sequência no ArrayList: C-1, P-2, C-3, R-4, P-5, P-6, R-7.

Aí suponha que desejo extrair todas senhas do ArrayList pelo caixa 1, mas o caixa1 deve priorizar as senhas P(Prioritárias) que deve seguir o seguinte processo, remover na ordem de inserção: P-2, P-5, P-6.

Depois continuando a remoção através do metodo caixa1, ele deve continuar e remover na ordem que sobrou sem prioridade: C-1, C-3, R-4, R-7.

Código fonte do Jframe para atribuir o tipo e número ao ArrayList.

```
 private void clienteComumActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {         
        numero++;
        Senha senha = new Senha('C', numero);      
        listaSenhas.add(senha);      
        senhaGerada.setText(String.valueOf(senha.getTipo())+'-'+String.valueOf(senha.getNumero()));
    }                                          

    private void clientePrioritarioActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {   
        numero++;
        Senha senha = new Senha('P', numero);      
        listaSenhas.add(senha);      
        senhaGerada.setText(String.valueOf(senha.getTipo())+'-'+String.valueOf(senha.getNumero()));
    }
           
    private void clienteRapidoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {        
        numero++;
        Senha senha = new Senha('R', numero);      
        listaSenhas.add(senha);
        System.out.println("lista depois"+listaSenhas);
        senhaGerada.setText(String.valueOf(senha.getTipo())+'-'+String.valueOf(senha.getNumero()));
    }                                            

//Busca, apresentação e remoção  
   
    private void jbcaixa1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {             

        saidaCaixa.setText("Caixa 1");      
             
        Iterator<Senha> itr = listaSenhas.iterator();                              
          while(itr.hasNext()){
            Senha s = itr.next();            
            if (s.getTipo() == 'P') {                
            saidaSenha.setText(String.valueOf(s.getTipo())+'-'+String.valueOf(s.getNumero()));

            itr.remove();
                break;
            }                   
          }
    }                                      

    private void jbcaixa2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {             

        saidaCaixa.setText("Caixa 2");
       
        Iterator<Senha> itr = listaSenhas.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            Senha s = itr.next();
            itr.remove();
            saidaSenha.setText(String.valueOf(s.getTipo())+'-'+String.valueOf(s.getNumero()));
            break;
        }  
    }


public class Senha {
   private char tipo;
        private int numero;
        char contains;

    public Senha() {   // Metodo construtor
        this(' ', 0);  //Esta recebendo os parametros do construtor abaixo
    }
    //Construtor 2
    public Senha (char tipo, int numero) {
        this.setTipo(tipo);
        this.setNumero(numero);         
    }

    public char getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(char tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public int getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(int numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }     
}
```

Nesta parte do código tem uma condição para primeiro apresentar/remover todas senhas iniciadas em P na sequência de inserção, mas não sei como acrescentar lógica para depois poder apresentar/remover as outras senhas C/R respeitando a ordem de inserção.

> ```
> private void jbcaixa1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {             
>
>     saidaCaixa.setText("Caixa 1");      
>          
>     Iterator<Senha> itr = listaSenhas.iterator();                              
>       while(itr.hasNext()){
>         Senha s = itr.next();            
>           if (s.getTipo() == 'P') {                
>             saidaSenha.setText(String.valueOf(s.getTipo())+'-'+String.valueOf(s.getNumero()));
>
>             itr.remove();
>             break;
>         }                   
>       }
> ```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue exemplo abaixo, da pra percorrer novamente a sua lista de senhas depois que todas as senhas preferenciais já foram extraídas.

Outra forma de pensar neste problema é, quando você encontra uma senha preferencial no seu array, e ela seja removida, no final somente estarão presentes no array as demais senhas não preferenciais.

Também pode criar mais lista para dar apoio a esta operação, criar uma lista a mais para as senhas preferenciais e uma outra lista para as demais. Nesse caso usaria um if/else, tudo que for "P" adiciona na lista preferencial, do contrário é adicionado na outra lista. Porém desta forma você estará trabalhando com 3 listas ao mesmo tempo, algo que acredito ser desnecessário para o seu caso.

```
private void jbcaixa1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {             

    saidaCaixa.setText("Caixa 1");      
         
    Iterator<Senha> itr = listaSenhas.iterator();                              
      while(itr.hasNext()){
        Senha s = itr.next();            
          if (s.getTipo() == 'P') {                
                saidaSenha.setText(String.valueOf(s.getTipo())+'-'+String.valueOf(s.getNumero()));
    
                itr.remove();
                break;
 

           }
// uma forma de se fazer isso é criar um novo loop depois de todas as senhas preferênciais terem sido extraídas.
          while(itr.hasNext()){
                Senha s = itr.next();
                    saidaSenha.setText(String.valueOf(s.getTipo())+'-'+String.valueOf(s.getNumero()));
                    itr.remove();              
              }
```

Comment: Agradeço contribuição. Na verdade eu acabei recebendo dica para usar um return no final do primeiro laço, substituindo o break;, assim impedindo que ele executasse o segundo laço em caso de não achar o valor preferencial que estava causando erro no código.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz a troca para um metodo, substituindo o break; no final do primeiro laço por um return;. Assim resolveu meu problema:

```
private void TestaSenha( String a) {           
        Iterator<Senha> itr = listaSenhas.iterator();           
            while(itr.hasNext()){                    
                Senha s = itr.next();                   
                    if (s.getTipo() == a) {                
                        saidaSenha.setText(String.valueOf(s.getTipo())+'-'+String.valueOf(s.getNumero()));                             
                        itr.remove();
                        System.out.println("lista depois"+listaSenhas);                                        
                            return;
                    }                  
            }
                      
        Iterator<Senha> itr2 = listaSenhas.iterator();
            if (listaSenhas.size()>0) {                                                  
                while(itr2.hasNext()) {
                    Senha r = itr2.next();                                        
                        saidaSenha.setText(String.valueOf(r.getTipo())+'-'+String.valueOf(r.getNumero())); 
                        itr2.remove();
                        System.out.println("itr2"+listaSenhas);
                            break;                                     
                }
            }
    }
```